# How can I recover a terminated snapshot on Google Cloud Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Though falsely that I would not be impacted by the Covid crisis... had my billing account terminated along with the cloud engine VM attached to it on 08/Jan/2021, the VM get stopped and terminated one month later on February 2021.

I solved the billing issue and reactivated the account on 28/Feb/2021, but never the less the VM was deleted, I solved the billing issue +- 10 days too late to be able to recover the VM in an automated way.

I had a daily snapshot scheduled on that VM... the billing support informed me that the snapshot retention period on Google's back-end is longer, I desperately need your help to recover that snapshot.

Here are the details of the deleted/terminated VM

```
- Project : my-gcloud-project-space
- Zone : europe-west6-b
- Instance name : intika-cloud-dw
- Instance ID : 39223103792027291
- Concerned VM Disk : projects/my-gcloud-project-space/zones/europe-west6-b/disks/intika-cloud-enc
- Instance link : projects/my-gcloud-project-space/zones/europe-west6-b/instances/intika-cloud-dw
- Zone link : projects/my-gcloud-project-space/zones/europe-west6-b
- Support chat transcript : case #27054228 (billing team, that informed me about the snapshot retention)
```

The snapshot should have been ran automatically on February as well, from the activity logs here is the time when I created that snapshot + its schedule,
but I am not sure 100% if it's the one running daily

```
- Start time : Mon Apr 20 2020 
- Resource name : projects/my-gcloud-project-space/zones/europe-west6-b/disks/intika-cloud-enc
- Name : snapshot-1
- Storage locations : europe-west6
- ID : 3738848292645164093
- Target ID : 6513980452485049482
- Target Link : googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-gcloud-project-space/zones/europe-west6-b/disks/intika-cloud-enc
```

Otherwise more recently I did a snapshot and delete it while troubleshooting a problem (sorry for the snapshot name)

```
- Insert time : Tue Nov 24 2020 12:30:28 
- Resource name : projects/my-gcloud-project-space/global/snapshots/*ucked-copy-europe-west6-b-20201123210016-co49zkqr
- ID : 2948064231289868347
- Target ID : 5871237080529607695
- Target link : googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-gcloud-project-space/global/snapshots/*ucked-copy-europe-west6-b-20201123210016-co49zkqr
```

How can I recover the snapshot from Google's back-end? Any recovered data is very valuable to me. Thanks a lot for your help it's really appreciated

Comment: If you don't see the snapshot in your account you'll have to contact Google.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there is not exact deadline or time interval before resources might be removed from a project, but if your billing account remains invalid for a protracted period, the resources will be removed and are not recoverable.

I found that it is mention at the [Resolve Cloud Billing issues](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#overview), If your billing account remains invalid for a protracted period, some resources might be removed from the projects associated with your account. For example, if you use Google Cloud, your Compute Engine resources might be removed. Removed resources are not recoverable.